# Creating Aged Invoice Summary in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Hi: I am looking to create a sheet which tallies the number of open invoices by client and age (0-30, 31-60, 61-90, 91-120, >120). Column A contains at least 1000 rows with 50 different clients, sorted. Clients get added and deleted on occasion. Column B contains the number of days each invoice is open, same number of rows. So the summary should be Client Name in first column, and 5 columns for the above 5 periods. Fifty total clients means 50 rows in the summary, plus a header.

What I've done so far: I can insert COUNTIF formulas `CountIf(B1:B15,"<60") - CountIf(B1:B15,"<31")` to come up with the correct tallies. But the ranges I am referring to change from file to file. A1:A15 is Client A today, tomorrow if may be A1:A29. If I could name the different ranges in Column A before I start, the formulas would be a snap: `CountIf(ClientA, "<60")`   Or maybe there's an easier way.

As a last resort, I could sort the list 50 times (for each client) and run the calcs after each sort, but that would be a LOT of code. And the client list changes from time to time, so the sort fields would need to be maintained. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No VBA needed. If you're using 2007 or later, take a look at the `COUNTIFS` function. Otherwise do a search on "counting with SUMPRODUCT."

Comment: take a look at [Excel MVP Charley Kyd: Use Excel's SUMPRODUCT
To Summarize Worksheet Data](http://www.exceluser.com/explore/sumproduct_11.htm) and [Excel MVP Charley Kyd: SUMPRODUCT series](http://www.exceluser.com/explore/sumproduct_12.htm)